# Restoring encrypted database in AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-sql-database, amazon-rds, database-restore

I'm trying to migrate my on-premise sql databases to AWS RDS. Here the issue is the database backups are encrypted.

So how I can restore an encrypted database (encryption was done in on-premise backup) in AWS RDS ? Is it possible to migrate the existing on-premise database keys and certificates in AWS RDS ?

Please help

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html - *"You can't restore from an encrypted backup in the Amazon S3 bucket."*.

Comment: You can take the backup, decrypt it e.g. locally, store it in S3 (the bucket itself can then use KMS SSE and then import that data into RDS.

Comment: As like SQL database certificates and keys what will be the same functionalities in AWS RDS ? How can I created certificates ?

Comment: In AWS you generally encrypt with KMS - there you can get keys of various types, however AWS will hold the private keys and will only ever hand the public key out. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/securing-data-in-amazon-rds-using-aws-kms-encryption/

Comment: Certificates are only really interesting for https domains, not for databases etc. and those are taken care of by ACM.